# Sending bits and parity bits over noisy channel

Tags: probability

Consider a sender is trying to send three information bits $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$ over a noisy
channel with error probability $$p = 0.001$$ That is with probability $p$ each bit may be flipped independently
from 0 to 1 and vice versa.

The sender adds three parity bits to it as follows:
$$a_4 = a_2 + a_3 \;(\text{mod } 2)$$
$$a_5 = a_1 + a_3 \;(\text{mod } 2)$$
$$a_6 = a_1 + a_2 \;(\text{mod } 2)$$

What happens if the sender only adds two parity bits $a_4$ and $a_5$?

Does this mean just a change in the probability? Meaning it will increase the chance of not recognizing if a bit was sent incorrectly?

Comment: What matters is the probability of getting the original bits right, for computing that you need to specify how you plan to use the parity bits to decode. Of course, in general (for a rational coder-decoder pair) adding redundacy (parity bits) should decrease the overall probabiblity of error.

Comment: @leonbloy So by what you are saying, the answer to the question (what happens if only $a_4$ and $a_5$ is sent) depends on the probability the original bits are right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all three parity bits you can actually correct any one error (out of the 6, 3 message + 3 parity).  However, if you only send a4 and a5 then you will be able to correct an error in bit a3 (if a4 and a5s values reflect it), but not any of the others.  An error of a1 and an error of a5 are indistinguishable (as with a2 and a4).  For error detection, this is still fine, just have the receiver request a resend from the transmitter.  But correctable errors reduce retransmissions, speeding up the system.

The probability of an uncorrectable error using all 3 bits is ${6\choose2} p^2 \cdot(1-p)^4\approx1.5\cdot10^{-5}$

The probability of an undetected error using just 2 bits is ${4\choose1} p (1-p)^4\approx0.004$